# How does the Scala toSeq:_* syntax work?

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

In the Scala code

```
val s = Set(List(1,2,3).toSeq:_*)
```

how does the `toSeq:_*` syntax work? I know what the code does, I know what `toSeq` does, I understand `List(1,2,3).toSeq:Seq[Int]`. Is `toSeq:_*` a special case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `toSeq` isn't accomplishing anything here, and should be omitted. The following is equivalent:

```
Set(List(1, 2, 3): _*)
```

(Or even better, just write `List(1, 2, 3).toSet`.)

Since you say you know what the code does, I'll assume you understand the `_*` type annotation that marks the list as a *sequence argument* (if not, see section 4.6.2 of [the language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)). This will work on any `Seq`, including `List`, so converting the list explicitly with `toSeq` is just extra clutter.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that the _* type annotation existed.